# Oracle - How to join multiple Tables with same FK and no other correlation between them. Avoiding row duplication

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm Making a Query to get the Payments of a Invoice.
But since i can have, multiple cards, Accounts Receivable and Money (cash and change).
is it possible to make this work without using function, Unions and subqueries?
all tables have 300k+ records, and i want to make a view for ease of use/maintain.
however when i use union on views perfromance drops drastically

THE FOLLOWING EXEMPLE

**Invoice**

| INVOICE |
| --- |
| 113806 |

**Invoice -> entry**

| INVOICE | ID_ENTRY |
| --- | --- |
| 113806 | 387473 |

**Accounts Receivable**

| ID_ENTRY | ID_AR | DUE TO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 387473 | 31014 | 15/05/2022 |
| 387473 | 31015 | 15/06/2022 |

**Card**

| ID_ENTRY | ID_CARD | DUE TO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 387473 | 407214 | 01/01/2022 |

**Cash**

| ID_ENTRY | ID_CASH | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 387473 | 407214 | 10 |
| 387473 | 407215 | -5 |

**Query**

```
SELECT NAF.INVOICE_ENTRY, ADRE.ID_AR, ACAR.ID_CARD, ADIN.ID_CASH
FROM INVOICE N
INNER JOIN INVOICE_ENTRY NAF
    ON NAF.ID_INVOICE = N.ID_INVOICE
LEFT JOIN AR_ENTRY ADRE
    ON ADRE.ID_ENTRY = NAF.ID_ENTRY
LEFT JOIN CARD_ENTRY ACAR
    ON ACAR.ID_ENTRY = NAF.ID_ENTRY
LEFT JOIN CASH_ENTRY ADIN
    ON ADIN.ID_ENTRY = NAF.ID_ENTRY
WHERE N.ID_INVOICE = :ID_INVOICE
```

**Result**

| ID_ENTRY | ID_AR | ID_CARD | ID_CASH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 387473 | 31014 | 221396 | 407214 |
| 387473 | 31014 | 221396 | 407215 |
| 387473 | 31015 | 221396 | 407214 |
| 387473 | 31015 | 221396 | 407215 |

**Expected Result**

| ACERFIN | IDAD | IDCAR | IDDIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 387473 | 31014 | NULL | NULL |
| 387473 | 31015 | NULL | NULL |
| 387473 | NULL | 221396 | NULL |
| 387473 | NULL | NULL | 407214 |
| 387473 | NULL | NULL | 407215 |

Comment: There are no duplicate rows in you result. Can you also show us what you expected to be returned?

Comment: Sorry, my expected result did not paste. there it is.

Comment: "Union" seems to be the correct approach, from a very quick reading of your question. You say "union" makes things slow. That is almost certainly a sign of incorrect use. Are you using `union` (which is a mistake), or `union all` (notice **`all`**) as you should be using? `union all` is the correct operator to use in your problem, and `union all` adds almost no overhead to the execution time of the underlying queries.

Comment: I used union all, however, unless i'm really mistaken if i create a view with 
`table A UNION ALL Table B`  and then `Join view_x v on v.invoice = n.invoice`. wouldt it first union them all then place a where. since its like 8 tables that will compound this View each with 300k+ rows.

Comment: Still no duplicate rows in the result. PS [mre] PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [help]

Comment: Please put (good) answers in answer posts, not question posts. [ask] [answer] [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` on the `accounts_receivable`, `cash` and `card` tables and then join the result to the other tables:

```sql
SELECT u.*
FROM   invoice i
       INNER JOIN entry e
       ON (i.invoice = e.invoice)
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT id_entry AS acerfin, id_ar AS idad, NULL AS idcar, NULL AS iddin
         FROM   accounts_receivable
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id_entry, NULL, id_card, NULL
         FROM   card
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id_entry, NULL, NULL, id_cash
         FROM   cash
       ) u
       ON (e.id_entry = u.acerfin)
WHERE  i.invoice = 113806
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE invoice (INVOICE) AS
SELECT 113806 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE entry (INVOICE, ID_ENTRY) AS
SELECT 113806, 387473 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Accounts_Receivable (ID_ENTRY, ID_AR, DUE_TO) AS
SELECT 387473, 31014, DATE '2022-05-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 387473, 31015, DATE '2022-06-15' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Card (ID_ENTRY, ID_CARD, DUE_TO) AS
SELECT 387473, 407214, DATE '2022-05-01' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Cash (ID_ENTRY, ID_CASH, VALUE) AS
SELECT 387473, 407214, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 387473, 407215, -5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ACERFIN | IDAD | IDCAR | IDDIN |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 387473 | 31014 | *null* | *null* |
> | 387473 | 31015 | *null* | *null* |
> | 387473 | *null* | 407214 | *null* |
> | 387473 | *null* | *null* | 407214 |
> | 387473 | *null* | *null* | 407215 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0b8f2724a320226e76e4d5978513d37f)*